# Modern C++ pattern for ugly C struct allocation

Tags: c, c++11

I'm making an `ioctl` call from C++ into a driver I don't own/maintain, and I'm trying to sort out if there's a clean, "safe-ish" mechanism to  deal with some of the ugly struct allocation required.

Slimmed down version of some structures involved

```
// IOCTL expects an instance of this structure "first"
typedef struct {
   int param1;
   int param2;
} s_ioctl_request;

//... followed by an instance of this.  If attr_length
// is > sizeof(s_attr_header), more data is allowed to follow.
typedef struct {
   uint32_t attr_length;
   uint32_t attr_type;
} s_attr_header;

// Example that uses more data than just the header.
typedef struct {
   s_attr_header   hdr;
   uint32_t attr_param;
} s_attr_type1;

// Another example.
typedef struct {
   s_attr_header   hdr;
   uint32_t attr_param1;
   uint32_t attr_param2;
} s_attr_type2;
```

The ioctl requires that `s_ioctl_request` be immediately followed by an `s_attr_header`, or other struct containing it, where `attr_length` is set to the size of the outer struct in bytes.

In `C`, to write a wrapper for the `ioctl` it would be done via something along these lines:

```
int do_ugly_ioctl(int fd, int p1, int p2, s_attr_header * attr)
{  
   int res;      
   // Allocate enough memory for both structures.
   s_ioctl_request *req = malloc( sizeof(*req) + attr->hdr.attr_length );

   // Copy the 2nd, (variable length) structure after the first.
   memcpy( ((char*)req) + sizeof(*req), attr, attr->hdr.attr_length);

   // Modify params as necessary
   req->param1 = p1;
   req->param2 = p2;

   // Make the driver call, free mem, and return result.
   res = ioctl(fd, SOME_IOCTL_ID, req);
   free(req);
   return res;
}

// Example invocation.
s_attr_type1 a1;
a1.hdr.attr_length = sizeof(a1);
a1.hdr.attr_type   = 1;
do_ugly_ioctl(fd, 10, 20, &a1);
```

A couple options I'm thinking of, are:

1. Throw modern C++-isms out the window, and do exactly what I've shown above.
2. Allocate the storage with a std::vector, then do ugly casts with the resulting std::vector::data() pointer so at least I'm not doing `new[]` / `delete[]` or `malloc` / `free`.
3. Create a unique wrapper method for each `s_attr_type*` that uses its own "special" struct.  This seems "safest", i.e. least likely for the user of the wrapper method to screw it up.  And bonus points, allows pass-by-ref.

Method #3 example:

```
int do_ugly_ioctl(fd, int param1, int param2, s_attr_type2& attr){
  struct RequestData {
      s_ioctl_request ioreq;
      s_attr_type2    attr;
  };
  RequestData r;
  r.ioreq.param1 = param1;
  r.ioreq.param2 = param2;
  r.attr         = attr;
  r.attr.hdr.attr_length = sizeof(attr); // Might as well enforce this here.
  ioctl(fd, SOME_IOCTL_ID, (void*) &r);
}
```

So I guess some questions here are:

- Is it "worth it" to C++-ize a solution to this problem?  (as opposed to relying on the more error-prone C impl).
- If I go with method #3 or similar, is there anything that I can do with `<type_traits>` to make a template of this function and only accept structs with an `s_attr_header` as the first member?
- Any other brilliant ideas?

Comment: The C wrapper requires 8 lines of code. The C++ wrapper requires 10. I fail to see much improvement.

Comment: Option 2 is just hiding the allocations inside std::vector, so it's no improvement at all. In fact, option 2 is a terrible solution.

Comment: @CareyGregory I wouldn't say it is hidden because every C++-programmer knows what a vector does. It would call it encapsulated.

Comment: @CareyGregory - The C++ wrapper, when combined with templating, allows pass-by-ref.  In the `C` version, I would need to add 2-3 lines to check for `nullptr` / `NULL` for a "production quality" solution.  Using `std::vector` makes the code exception safe.  Somebody else modifying the C version of code down the road to where it `throws` introduces the possibility of a memory leak.  `std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[data_size])` achieves that as well, but is more verbose & less common than using `vector`.

Comment: To be perfectly frank here; I think you forgot "Option 4: realise you're too much of a delicate flower to have to put up with anything like IOCTLs, and probably should consider a career in embroidery."

Comment: @Brendan - Nothing like an ad-hominem attack that offers zero insight.  I've been dealing `ioctls` & low level code that (out of necessity) plays fast & loose with pointers and memory management for most of my career.  You can call me crazy or weak for trying to learn how to leverage modern tools to make my job easier and to make my code base more robust.  But while spending your days digging through kernel panics & stack traces "puts hair on your chest", it doesn't ship products faster.

Comment: You're working with a C-based interface that expects C-style parameters. Wrapping that up in C++ adds nothing other than unnecessary complexity since you've still got to get down to pointers to actually _use_ the interface. If you think `malloc` is so dangerous, there's nothing stopping you from implementing #3 using C++ as a "better C" rather than an OO language. Just make a `do_ugly_ioctl` for each type of `attr` struct and declare it as an auto. Problem solved. Future maintainers will thank you for not creating false safety using `std::vector::data()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally worth it, and your solution is quite nice.
You might want to declare your structures as `packed` (there are compiler extensions to achieve this) to avoid having extra padding when combining multiple structures.

You can also set the size of the structure within the constructor.

```
struct RequestData
{
      RequestData() : ioreq{}, attr{}
      {
        attr.hdr.attr_length =  sizeof(attr);
      }
      s_ioctl_request ioreq;
      s_attr_type2    attr;
 };
```

concerning your second question, you could split the assignment in two, it's not too nice but it's easy and if you pass something without a correct header, it will lead to a compiler error:

```
template<typename Attr>
int do_ugly_ioctl(fd, int param1, int param2, Attr& attr){
  struct RequestData {
      s_ioctl_request ioreq;
      Attr    attr;
  };
  RequestData r;
  r.ioreq.param1 = param1;
  r.ioreq.param2 = param2;
  s_attr_header hdr = Attr.hdr; //this will lead to compilation error if the type is not what we expect
  (void) hdr;
  r.attr     = attr;
  r.attr.hdr.attr_length = sizeof(attr); // Might as well enforce this here.
  ioctl(fd, SOME_IOCTL_ID, (void*) &r);
}
```

Comment: The fact that accessing the header member causes an error when its not there was my mental "missing link" in my method #3.